# Testlink 1.9.4 integration with bugzilla 4.2.3

Tags: testing

I have successfully installed Testlink 1.9.4 and bugzilla 4.2.3 in wamp server on a windows machine.I found out that in order to connect testlink version 1.9.4 with any bug tracker you no longer need to make use of the .cfg file and therefore make use of the 'Issue tracker management' instead.

I therefore went to project, then under "test project" selected "Issue tracker management".Chose bugzilla interface db and clicked 'Show configuration example'.Then I copied and pasted making appropriate changes according to my needs.However when I go to 'Test Execution' screen the bug icon doesnt appear for failed test cases and i get the below error message at the top of the screen

"Attention Please: Something is preventing connection to Bug Tracking System, and is going to create performance issues. Please contact your TestLink Administrator".

I believe there is some specific steps which i'm missing to set up the right configuration with Testlink 1.9.4.I tried to look out for any latest documentation but could'nt find any.

Comment: Did you check that the credentials in config_db.inc.php are correct? Have you looked in the logs? What is $tlCfg->log_level set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, create issue tracker by using Iss Tracker Managerment.( Just as you did )
Secondly, indicate a issue tracer (which you created) when creating a test project.